# How to read a binary tree from the console, so to be able to workout its nodes?

Tags: c#, graph, binary-tree

I need to proceed with the nodes of a binary tree, but I'm not sure how to pass it as an input.
Let's say I have the tree:

```
     11
    12 13
   14 15 16
  17 18 19 20
```

Then I have a generic class `Node<T>`

```
public class Node<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }

        public List<Node<T>> Children { get; set; }

        public bool HasChild { get; set; }

        public bool HasParent { get; set; }

        public Node(T value)
        {
            this.Value = value;
            this.Children = new List<Node<T>>();
        }
    }
```

I should be adding each node to the list of nodes - Children, but in what order, so I keep the hierarchy of the tree?

Answer (score 0):

Give user a choice which to first select the order to enter such as Preorder/Inorder/Postorder. And then process the input accordingly. Hope you will be able to code that.

Comment: So if it was specified as inorder and the input was given as `1 2 3` what's the root?  Is it a root of 2 with 1 and 3 as children, or `1` as the root with a child of 2, and with 2 having a child of 3?  You can turn any tree into an inorder list, but you can't know what list that in-order tree creates (unless you don't care which of the many possible valid trees is used).

Comment: As the inorder definition says, the root element has to be in between the Left and Right Node. So 1 is the left element, 2 is the root and 3 is the right lement.

Comment: As I said before, it would be a perfectly valid tree to have 1 as the root, `2` as the right node of 1, and then 3 as the right node of 2.  It's not a balanced tree, but it's a valid one.  You could also have 3 as the root and 2 as the left node of 3 and 1 as the left node of 2.  All three of those trees would generate `1 2 3` as the output of inorder traversal.

Answer (score 0):

One representation of a tree is as a series of pairs; each value and it's parent (`null` for the root).  Your tree might be represented like:

```
null 11
11 12
11 13
12 14
13 15
13 16
...
```

Comment: Yeah, I got this part, but if we suppose I pass the tree as a string on the console and I have to workout this string, so I keep the pairs as they are - [11 12][11 13][12 14][12 15]... how to proceed? It looks too abstract to me :)

Comment: @Todo For each pair you find the value on the left and then add the value on the right as a child.

Comment: My ignorance is: If i pass the tree as a string and store it in an array, the nodes enter the array in the sequence: 11, 12, 13, 14, 15... thus I lose the parent/child connection... Of course if I preorder the nodes in pairs and pass them to the console, then it's easy. But reading from a string is what makes me not able to think of a solution.

Comment: @Todo It should be entered just as I showed; or at least that's how I'd do it.  Have each pair separated by a line break.  Read in a line, break it up into the parent/child, find the parent, add the child, then read the next line.  If they're in a mixed up order then put them all in a `Dictionary` with the key being the parent and the value being the value of the child.  Then just find the root node, add that, then find all of the values for that key from the dictionary, then go through all of the children and find *their* children through the `Dictionary`, etc.

Comment: Servy thank you very much for your help, but if I have to preorder few hundred nodes by hand? It would be crazy, so that's why I'm searching for an automated technique. P.S The nodes can have the same values, so Dictionary is not the right track as it allows only unique keys.

Comment: @Todo If you can't ensure that the parent of each node will exist when the child is added then use the second approach I just mentioned in the comments in which you add them all to a dictionary first.

Answer (score 0):

You can give on the first line of input two integers, say 'n' the number of nodes and 'm' the number of arcs. Then you provide 'n' lines with the identifiers of the nodes and afterwards 'm' lines with the arcs.

As you parse the identifiers you can create your Node objects, and then when you pass the arcs you add the children properly.

Your graph would look like this then:

```
10 12
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
11 12
11 13
12 14
12 15
13 15
13 16
14 17
14 18
15 18
15 19
16 19
16 20
```

This way you forget about the order in which the arcs and given. You can identify afterwards the head because it'll be the only node without a parent.

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
              public static void Main()
              {
               Node root = new Node(50);
               BinaryTree BT = new BinaryTree(root);
               Node left = new Node(17);
               Node right = new Node(76);
               root.left = left;
               root.right = right;
               Node lleft = new Node(9);
               Node lright = new Node(23);
               Node rleft = new Node(54);
               root.left.left = lleft;
               root.left.right = lright;
               root.right.left = rleft;
               Node llright = new Node(14);
               Node llrleft = new Node(12);
               root.left.left.right = llright;
               root.left.left.right.left = llrleft;
               Node lrright = new Node(19);
               root.left.right.left = lrright;
               Node rlright = new Node(72);
               Node rlrleft = new Node(67);
               root.right.left.right = rlright;
               root.right.left.right.left = rlrleft;

                      }
```